# Can the second "the" be omitted in "the owner and (the) chairman of the company"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Is it correct to omit the article the in this sentence?

> Lucy, the owner and the chairman of **the** company, has gone to Philippines to attend the conference.

I mean instead of doubling the article *the*, is it ok to write
"the owner and chairman of the company"?

Answer (score 1):

Lucy, the owner and the chairman of the company, has gone to Philippines to attend the conference.

This is how to do it:

Lucy, **the owner and chairman of the company**, has gone to **the** Philippines to attend the conference.

If you are two specific things at once, you don't repeat the.

He was the CEO and chairman of the company for many years.

However, you have to use *the* or *a* before the word company.

The country name for the Philippines takes the.